# Can multiple sub-domains share the same document root?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, subdomain

I want to set up per client sub domains e.g.

`clientA.topleveldomain.com` and
`clientB.topleveldomain.com`

I presume I can do this in IIS by having one site and then setting up the bindings for that site e.g.

> Port 80 - clientA.topleveldomain.com
>
> Port 80 - clientB.topleveldomain.com

However, I need independent logins for both sub-domains. That is, once a user has authenticated on clientA.top..., they should not then be authenticated on clientB.top....

Likewise both would need independent sessions so moving between sub-domains would not preserve any session information.

Would this work "out of the box" using bindings or would I need to have each client as a separate website?

The site will be an ASP.Net MVC site running on IIS 7. I would want to use ASP.Net forms authentication.

Comment: I think that comes down to the cookie domains generated by ASP.NET and / or IIS, but I can't remember where that's set. It may also be the NTLM authentication domain set up in IIS. Try logging in to one and inspecting the URL in the authentication challenge in the traffic, and then the path in the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

> Would this work "out of the box" using bindings or would I need to
>   have each client as a separate website?

Yes, because out of the box Session and Forms Authentication cookies are not shared cross sub-domains. But an even better would be to explicitly set the `domain`property of those cookies in your web.config:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/signin" 
       cookieless="UseCookies" 
       protection="All" 
       timeout="30" 
       slidingExpiration="false"
       domain="clientA.topleveldomain.com" />
```

If on the other hand you are using Integrated Windows Authentication then it will be much harder because there are no cookies involved in the authentication process.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I wanted to try and have one web.config for all sub-domains.

Comment: I am 99.99999% sure that it will work out of the box without setting the domain. I just suggested it by precaution.